# Application Name not changed even though change Display name. and app name has .IPA extension

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle

I am facing very strange issue. I am not able to change **application display name**. 
 and unfortunately installed  application name has **`.ipa`**  extension which is bundle name  
 Here is Screen shot of plist (if you need code then i can edit and put it screen shot is easy to see)

[image]

Here is Screen shot of issue

[image]

Following not working for me..
...

I also tried to change from Build Setting display name  
I tried to delete and re-install app. 
I tried Clean Derived data. 
I tried clean project.
I tried to quit xcode.

Any Help or suggestion appreciated

Comment: do you use Localisable string in your project?

Comment: @KamleshShingarakhiya Nope :(

Comment: app name is like Something-Cafe.ipa  , i don't understand from where .ipa comes ? that `Something-Cafe` is my bundle ID

Answer (score 3):

Create new string file named `InfoPlist.strings` in string file add this string

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "YOUR APP NAME";
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Okay Let me try

Comment: I have added `InfoPlist.strings` same as you told but not working :(

Comment: Did you search to whole project with Something-Cafe.ipa?

Comment: This solution worked !! in simulator but in device not working

Answer (score 2):

Go to Project `Build settings` Search for `Product Name` then set what ever you want.

[image]

Comment: Do you think it is ipad issue ?

Comment: You need to change the .ipa Name?

Comment: When I install application it has .ipa extension !! i don't want this

Comment: try doing clean build folder

Comment: ok go to Build settings and search with the complete. you may find something